# How to stream all android audio output to server?

Tags: android, audio, streaming

I have looked high and low and not found exactly what I am looking for. I know everything is possible, so I hope that some of you may be able to point me in the right direction.

How, from Android, can I take all audio output and send it up to my server, so that it may be streamed to say a computer or another phone? I have the server aspect down, I'm just not exactly sure how to go about this with Android. I have a bit of Android Development experience, but have never tried this.

TL;DR How to Send ALL Audio From Phone > Server so it can be sent to another device. (Or the closest possible solution)

Thanks!

Comment: I recommend searching for one of the many similar questions along these lines.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! As I have mentioned, I have searched, and other than static files, I have come up empty.

Comment: Your question is too broad. Which audio stream are you specifically talking about capturing? Between the music player and the speaker? Between the incoming voice call and the speaker? Between the outgoing voice call and the cell network? Or the only one which has an API - Microphone input to your app.

Comment: Thanks. And sorry for being broad. I meant all system sounds. Like if you were to hook up a phone to a bluetooth speaker, you would hear everything. All of THAT audio, sent up to  server.